# Mathastext: Wrong digits in math-mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontspec, fourier, mathastext

I'm using `fourier` and `erewhon` as my main (serif) text and math fonts. I want to use `TeX Gyre Heros` as *sans* font. Because this font has no math support, I use `mathastext` to fake it **only** for the sans font without changing the *serif* font.

However, despite using the `subdued` option of `mathastext`, it changes the digits of the *serif* font in math mode.

Adding the `nodigits` option to `mathastext` fixes the problem for the serif font, but no longer changes the digits for the sans font.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{erewhon}
\usepackage[subdued,italic]{mathastext}

\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\Mathastext[sans]
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}
123 $123$
\textsf{123 \MTversion{sans}{$123$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: AFAIK "sans"  is a shorthand for "sansserif". So your aim is somewhat confusing. ..

Comment: @Jhor Oh well, thanks for the heads up. I fixed my question.

Comment: (quick summary for passers-by) This was a bug in mathastext which has been fixed in version `1.3t`.

Comment: For those still running into this with modern mathastext versions, keep in mind that (as stated in the mathastext documentation) you must load fontspec **before** mathastext  and with the the **no-math** option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in [`mathastext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) relative to its "subdued" mode. Brief explanation: `mathastext` reassings mathcodes of letters and digits and some ascii characters. When "subdued" mode was added, this was done not by reverting the mathcode changes (the package does not keep memory of earlier situation) but by hacking into the LaTeX math versions in order for the Font to be used to match the original, un-modified, fonts for either letters or operators.

For some reason I have forgotten, when copying over the pristine "letters" and "operators" status to the `mathastext` own math groups, `mathastext` deliberately modifies the font encoding to be the `\encodingdefault` (at time of loading `mathastext`). In the MWE where `mathastext` is loaded after `fontspec`, this encoding default will be `TU`, hence, rather than storing `\T1/futs/m/n` (as set up by fourier package for digits) in its own digits font for subdued mode, it stores `\TU/futs/m/n`. This then causes:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/futs/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 37.
```

which explains the altered looks of digits in math mode.

In the case where `mathastext` is loaded before `fontspec`, and after `fourier`, the `\encodingdefault` is the `T1`, not `TU` and all goes well.

I have forgotten the rationale behind this usage of `\encodingdefault`. There is also some code to deliberately replace `OT1` by `T1` if `\encodingdefault` is `OT1`. All of this was done at a stage of developement of `mathastext` when it had never been tested with xelatex/lualatex/fontspec anyhow.

One could imagine for the OP's problem modifying `\encodingdefault` back from `TU` to `T1` for the duration of loading `mathastext` after `fontspec` but from brief look at code this would give unexpected consequences due to some other usages of `\encodingdefault` in the package code.

Of course, one can also fix this by re-doing the `mathastext` hacks, but this is a bit scary code. It would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{erewhon}
\usepackage[subdued,italic]{mathastext}
\makeatletter
  \def\mst@reserved#1\getanddefine@fonts\symletters#2#3\@nil{%
        \def\mst@normalmv@letter{#2}}
  \expandafter\mst@reserved\mv@normal\@nil
  \def\mst@reserved#1\getanddefine@fonts\symletters#2#3\@nil{%
        \def\mst@boldmv@letter{#2}}
  \expandafter\mst@reserved\mv@bold\@nil
  \def\mst@reserved#1\getanddefine@fonts\symoperators#2#3\@nil{%
        \def\mst@normalmv@operator{#2}}
  \expandafter\mst@reserved\mv@normal\@nil
  \def\mst@reserved#1\getanddefine@fonts\symoperators#2#3\@nil{%
        \def\mst@boldmv@operator{#2}}
  \expandafter\mst@reserved\mv@bold\@nil
%%
  % \edef\mst@tmp{\encodingdefault} % NO!
  \def\mst@reserved#1/#2/#3/#4/{\gdef\mst@debut{#1}\gdef\mst@reste{#2/#3/#4}}
  \begingroup\escapechar\m@ne
      % \xdef\mst@funnyoti{\expandafter\string\csname OT1\endcsname}
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \mst@reserved\expandafter\string\mst@normalmv@operator/
  \endgroup
  % \ifx\mst@debut\mst@funnyoti\ifx\mst@tmp\mst@oti\def\mst@tmp{T1}\fi\fi
  \edef\mst@normalmv@operator{\expandafter\noexpand\csname
                               %\mst@tmp/\mst@reste\endcsname}
                               \mst@debut/\mst@reste\endcsname}
  \begingroup\escapechar\m@ne
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \mst@reserved\expandafter\string\mst@boldmv@operator/
  \endgroup
  % \ifx\mst@debut\mst@funnyoti\ifx\mst@tmp\mst@oti\def\mst@tmp{T1}\fi\fi
  \edef\mst@boldmv@operator{\expandafter\noexpand\csname
                             %\mst@tmp/\mst@reste\endcsname}
                             \mst@debut/\mst@reste\endcsname}
%  \AtEndOfPackage{
  \typeout{** ...correcting subdued mode...}
  \expandafter\SetSymbolFont@ \expandafter\mv@normal\mst@normalmv@letter\symmtletterfont
  \expandafter\SetSymbolFont@ \expandafter\mv@bold\mst@boldmv@letter\symmtletterfont
  \expandafter\SetSymbolFont@ \expandafter\mv@normal\mst@normalmv@operator\symmtoperatorfont
  \expandafter\SetSymbolFont@ \expandafter\mv@bold\mst@boldmv@operator\symmtoperatorfont
  \typeout{** ...done.}
%  }
\makeatother

\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\Mathastext[sans]
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}

123 $123$
% \textsf{123 \MTversion{sans}{$123$}}

\MTversion{sans}
123 $123$

\MTversion{normal}

\thispagestyle{empty}\showoutput
\end{document}
```

Of course it is not practical to add such a big hack to preamble (I could reduce its size but kept close to original, just to modify it here and there). Hopefully some update to `mathastext` will fix this, but the author will have to remember why in first place the code insisted on using `\encodingdefault` (there must be a reason...).

[image]

Comment: a fix has been incorporated to release 1.3s

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the fix! I've just tried version 1.3s and it works with the MWE from my original question!

Comment: thanks for testing the 1.3s 2018/08/21 and reporting back! hopefully it will work in other contexts as well.

Comment: ah sorry. I make a mistake in 1.3s which did not show in your MWE (due to presence of fourier package). Hence there will be 1.3t 2018/08/22 ...

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my case, 1.3s already works well. When I look at the source of tex packages, I always wonder why there are not more bugs :)

Comment: The 1.3t is now submitted to CTAN and should appear there in a few days at most.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that 1.3t still works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the wrong digits is fixed, if `mathastext` is loaded *before* `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[subdued,italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{erewhon}

\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\Mathastext[sans]
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}
123 $123$
\textsf{123 \MTversion{sans}{$123$}}
\end{document}
```

However, the documentation of `mathastext` clearly states that this **should not be done** (p. 21)!

Despite fixing the digits, `mathastext` still changes some math mode font metrics for the *serif* font, but I can live with that.

Comment: side note: use `\MTversion*{sans}` if you don't want to change text font. With `\MTversion{sans}` as in your MWE you don't need the `\textsf` (but may still need the `{..}` to limit the scope). Also, on Mac OS with xelatex, I need `TeX Gyre Heros` not `Tex Gyre Heros` spelling with TL2018.

Comment: I didn't know about the starred version `\MTversion*` - thanks for pointing that out. I used `\textsf` for comparison with the sans font in text mode, but you're right, it's not required for `\MTversion`. The name `Tex Gyre Heros` is used by TL2016 (yeah, I should probably perform an update, but I want to finish my thesis first).